# Ability to search my stuff?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

There's currently no good way of searching through my questions or answers..

This wasn't really a problem until the questions/answers were paginated, as I could quickly scan through or ctrl+f the page.. Now I have to click through countless AJAX-paginated pages to find it, or try and use Google to find it.

Two possible ideas:

- A "filter" input box above the "Questions" and "Answers" section (I think this should be able to use the same AJAX'y page loading stuff, just returning the search results rather than page x)
- A new bit of search syntax, which would be more flexible (but less obvious). Maybe `[user:dbr]` - which could be combined with other terms: `[user:dbr] [python] imports", or quickly search for another users stuff:`[user:Someone Else]`

Comment: +1 for the filter idea. Something similar to the search on /users and /tags pages. That would make finding your stuff snappy in the majority of cases.

Comment: this is becoming a big problem for me with 194 questions !

Comment: +1 for filter. Ease of navigating through my Q&A had been on my mind for long. Good you posted the question.

Comment: @Simon: This is a disastrous for me with +400 questions. - I use at the moment five SO-accounts such that I can keep order of the questions. - I see that SO is becoming more like Word, since you cannot abstract things like in LaTeX. I hope that competition will drive SO to improvements.

Comment: How do I list all my unanswered questions? I have now > 100 questions in total and i want to close as many of them as possible.

Comment: @kimsia See [the blog post on search](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/) from the accepted answer. Search for `user:me hasaccepted:0`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is [now possible](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/)!

For example, if I wanted to find all my objective-c questions, I could search for..

> [`user:745 [objective-c]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:745+%5Bobjective-c%5D)

Also,

> user: me

works as an alias for your own user id if you are logged in

Comment: The script does do the job, but having this added as a easy to use feature is the site's job, not the users'.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use Google as a backup:

"site:stackoverflow.com dbr php jquery code"

Comment: This is not enough, since Google has difficulties in searching questions specific to coding.

Answer (score 4):

There's now an easy way to search all of your favorites, answers, and questions from any page on any so-site: [SO-Family Quick-Reference to Q's, A's, and Fav's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/so-family-quick-reference-to-qs-as-and-favs-last-update-07-21-2009)

Comment: Indeed, the search works nicely

Answer (score 0):

try using the advanced search operator

`userid:{your user id} [tag] apples`

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10934/search-is-hard-lets-go-shopping

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `is:answer` to your search params to search your answers.

*Example:*

```
user:me is:answer your-search-term
```