# How to search my own questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Ability to search my stuff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff)

I can't find a question I made long time ago. I tried searching it, but there is much noise (other people's questions). Can I specify a user in the search box?

**Edit**
This feature request has been completed: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/

Comment: It's not yet possible, but it has been requested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be somewhere on this list (especially if you add some more context to it):

http://www.google.es/search?q="jader+dias"+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your questions list on your profile? Just click one of the last pages.