# Filter your questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, search, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to search my stuff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff)

Sometimes I want to go back to an answer I got from a question or check an answer I answered, say, last year but I wouldn't be able to find it...because you have to go through 9 pages or so of your questions and answers.

I think that it would very useful if some sort of Filter was implemented (like in the [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) Page) that would be used to help you traverse your questions and answers easily and find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to search your own answers on Stack Overflow, you can use [AskJonSkeet](http://askjonskeet.com) - it doesn't just index *my* answers. The URL format is

```
http://www.askjonskeet.com/user/[userid]/[username]/search/
```

e.g.

```
http://www.askjonskeet.com/user/1288/bill-the-lizard/search/
```

Of course it would be nice to have something like this built into the SE engine - apart from anything else, I believe AskJonSkeet only indexes SO, not the other sites - but you may find it a helpful workaround for the moment.

Comment: +1 Lolz. I have to give you credit for this, awesome idea and I love the quote. :)

Comment: ooh very interesting, will be using this quite a lot; Thanks Jon

Comment: ...bleh, can't vote up yet :/

Comment: Don't give me credit for it in terms of implementation - I didn't write it!

Comment: yea, but if it wasn't for you, it probably wouldn't have been written ;p