# Filter my own questions based on Tags

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, filtering, users

I have nearly 170 questions in my user page...

How to filter my own questions based on Tags?

For ex: I want to filter questions tagged `javascript`....

Any suggestion....

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the tag list on the bottom of your profile page and click the tag. This is the same as (e.g.) putting

> user:146857 [javascript]

into the search box. This will show all your posts, i.e. questions and answers, in the specific tag. To only show the questions, you can use this trick:

> user:146857 [javascript] views:0

You can replace the user number 146857 with "me", i.e.

> user:me [javascript] views:0