# Is there a possibility to search among my questions/answers only?

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to search my stuff?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff)

I have more than a hundred of asked questions and it's rather difficult to find manually the certain question of mine if it's not the best by votes/views.

So, how can I search only among my questions or answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by entering `user:me` in the search box.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search for a full list of options.