# Can there be a more comprehensive UI for advanced search?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, stack-exchange, search

At first I was going to ask about having [advanced search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff) (including all [options](https://stackoverflow.com/search)), but then I realised that it was already there.

Even though I like the syntax, maybe an advanced search UI (well, it would be a simple page) that only assists users in entering *'[advanced super ninja search options](https://stackoverflow.com/search)'* would make sense?

Comment: I feel a *Let me Google that for you* coming up

Comment: @Ivo, obviously not (also been there done that; I am not looking for latest firefox stackoverflow plugin; but I am suggesting improvements for the user interface on the search page. specifically on advanced super ninja search options).

Answer (score 4):

I put together the [Stack Exchange Advance Search Options Page](http://www.seasop.com/), a form that submits to the SO search script, just to try and give it a user interface.  Give it a try, and please let me know what you think.  Any feedback at all would help me improve it.

Comment: You registered a domain for it? lol

Comment: I did a search with terms "IList", tags "c#", user "me" and it didn't work. I think it's the # in the tag that's breaking it.

Comment: @Jon: I almost didn't register one, but they're practically free, so I figured "why not?"  I didn't like having my hosts name embedded in the URL.

Comment: @Jon: Also, nice catch on the `[c#]` tag.  That's fixed now (and I'm sure there are other special characters that I'll need to address).  Can't believe I didn't test with that one to begin with.  :)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the fix. [c++] is another broken one. [.net] and tags including a dash work.

Comment: @Jon: Yeah, I was fixing `[c++]` while you were commenting.  :)  Embarrassing... I have a badge in that one.

Comment: Fix confirmed. Also, sneaky script to include the Google Analytics stuff. Too bad I've already blocked the Google domain for that. ;)

Comment: Hmmmm... I think the search terms need to be escaped. Try searching with term "[index]". Edit: errrr... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22[index]%22+[c%23] explodes the search, and putting the term after the tag simply strips it. Might as well leave it be, the searching is pretty messed up to have to code around it's weird behaviours.

Comment: @Jon: Hmm... that is a weird one.  "[index]" doesn't make it through, but other quoted terms like "boost library" work just fine.  I think the SO search script didn't like the combination of quotes and brackets.

Comment: Yeah, it's tough to tell if your page is working when it's tough to tell if SO search is working. :D

Comment: It's very nice, Bill! One thing, though, the Votes/Views/Answers don't seem to register a value of 0, it appears to be identical to leaving the field blank. They work as expected with 1 or higher, though. Oh, and your bottom text says "offcially".

Comment: @Grace: Nice catch!  PHP and I had differing views on the meaning of "equality" on that one, but I relented.  Thank you.  (Thanks for the typo alert too.  I should have chosen a font that I can actually *read*!)

Comment: +1 Thanks Bill, this is along the lines I thought about.

Answer (score 0):

This has come up once for me.

**HR Droid:**

> Can you point me to some interview
>   questions that we can use to pre-screen
>   applicants so you stop complaining
>   about their quality?

**Me:**

> There's a bunch on stackoverflow.com ,
>   just use the search. I think the tag
>   is interview-questions.

**HR Droid:**

> Can you point me to some interview
>   questions that we can use to pre-screen
>   applicants so you stop complaining
>   about their quality?

Quite the vicious cycle, but I don't think the search gets in the way of most people. Disclaimer, I have never, ever dissed the search. Just the results and they have improved quite a bit over the last year.