# GUI to search my account only?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

I'd like to be able to search SO for my questions and my questions only. As of now, the only way I see that as being possible is if I search for my name in the search box. Being that I may be mentioned elsewhere and that other people may have similar usernames, This can be quite limiting.

Can we get a "Search my account" feature please? I'm extending this request to a graphical button, like "advanced search" or something.

Comment: Well, there was [this question asking for an Advanced Search UI](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54966/can-there-be-a-more-comprehensive-ui-for-advanced-search). In particular, [Bill's UI](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54966/can-there-be-a-more-comprehensive-ui-for-advanced-search/55684#55684) was functional, although I don't know if it's had any recent work done on it or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can restrict your searches to posts by yourself by appending `user:me` before your search terms.

See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search for all of the search options.

Comment: Well, I'd like to see some sort of GUI for this. Thanks though!

Comment: @Moshe: technically it is a GUI..

Comment: @Kop - I mean a GUI, like Bills UI mentioned above.

Comment: @Moshe: mine was a joke, I was saying that technically since it's a textbox in a browser it **is** a guy =)