# Ability to search in your Answers/Question from your profile

Tags: feature-request, search, profile-page

Often I remember answering a question but can't remember the answer I gave.

It would be nice to be able to search your answers or questions for specific key words from within your profile page.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this can be done by including the following in the search box:

`user:me is:answer`