# How to search for keywords in posts one only indirectly participated in?

Tags: support, search

The `user:id` option restricts search to questions by user `id` (e.g. "`me`"), but here's my situation:

I asked a question and remember one answer to it contained a specific keyword, but I don't remember which question it was. How can I search all answers to all my questions for a specific keyword? As an example, how to find [this unix.SE comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62261/how-to-tee-dropping-all-cr-lines-only-in-the-file-but-not-stdout#comment88673_62264) searching for "process substitution" - or, while we're at it, for "`>(`"?

Comment: The search page likely doesn't have this capability.  You may be able to write a data.SE query for it though.

Comment: I would resort to google-hacking for this , though i'm unsure if gogle indexes everythig

Comment: Have you looked through the answers to this question?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this out.  Mighty proud of myself, too.  :o)

Go to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and paste this in:

```
Select Top 30 
  P1.ID, 
  P1.ParentId, 
  P1.PostTypeID, 
  P1.OwnerUserID, 
  P1.Body, 
  P2.ID, 
  P2.ParentId, 
  P2.PostTypeID, 
  P2.OwnerUserID, 
  P2.Body,   
  Comments.Text, 
  Comments.UserID 
From Posts P1
Left Join Posts P2
On P1.ID = P2.ParentID
Left Join Comments 
On Comments.PostID = P1.ID 
Where P1.OwnerUserID = 'Your User ID' 
AND P2.Body like '%Your Search Phrase%'
```

I'm sure someone better with the Data Explorer can whip up something better, but I was able to use this to find an answer that contained a particular phrase in it, which someone gave to one of my own questions.

I think you were asking about a Unix site so the link might be different, and the available fields might be different too, but the above works fine on SE.

Comment: Very neat! It doesn't search through comments, but at least for answers to one's own questions this seems to work just fine :) Though one may have to increase the `30` if one posted many questions. And I guess with some minor modifications this would even search through answers to questions oneself has _answered_ instead of asked. By the way, you can use the [permalink](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix%20and%20linux/query/147744) feature to re-use a query later on, and via the 'Switch sites' button below 'Run Query' you can change the site that is queried

Comment: @TobiasKienzler - If you want to search comments too, then I think you can add an **OR** operator to that last line that will search for the same string in Comments.Text.  Something like: **AND (P2.Body like '%Your Search Phrase%' OR Comments.Text like '%Your Search Phrase%')**  Or you may need to left join table Comments to P2 in order to do that, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

On your user page, there is an 'Activity' tab, which shows all of your recent history.  While it may not be easily searchable, it is browseable, and may give you what you need.

To get there, select your user page, then click on 'Activity.'

[image]

You will note, for example, that posts you "revised" will appear in the list.

Comment: Sure, but that's not searchable, and I'm looking for a comment/answer someone _else_ posted

Comment: Um, I said "It isn't searchable, only browseable." Sorry - I don't have access to add features, only give you what may get you closer.  I agree with you, this would be nice, but it doesn't exist

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the relevant part is that this allows looking through one's _own_ activities, but what I search is someone else's activity _on_ one of my own posts

Answer (score 0):

For the question posed, try this:

```
"process substitution" is:answer
```

Unfortunately, without writing your own SE query (which CAN be done) there's no way to filter based on questions you're associated with in this context.  This will at least narrow it down a bit, depending on how unique the keyword is.