# Can we add a search to questions in a user's profile?

Tags: feature-request, search, profile-page

Sometimes I'll have a question that I know I asked before, maybe years ago, and got a good answer to, and need to refer back to. I could probably eventually find it using the relevant site's main search, but it would be a lot faster to be able to just search within my profile through the couple hundred questions I've asked before. It would also be nice to be able to filter them by tags.

Same with answers and favorites, now that I think of it.

Edit: I did see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff?rq=1), but that's 6 years old and I'm not convinced it's the ideal way of implementing this. I don't see why I should have to type my own username....seems to me it would be a lot more intuitive to be able to just *go to my profile* and type in a searchbox right there. The third-to-top answer on that question is actually hilarious in terms of the amount of effort required. Recommended reading.

Comment: Wonderful Idea!

Answer (score 10):

The user's ID is shown in the search bar on top right whenever you're in his profile page. You can simply add your search term there and click enter. If you want questions only, just add `is:q`. Altogether, you have got this feature already and there is nothing necessary to do.

I would see it reasonable to some extent if the search preset included `is:q` on the Activity->Questions tab and `is:a` on the Activity->Answers tab implicitly, though.

[image]

Comment: I think @aerovistae wants it to be simpler than that.

Comment: @NoviceSEMetaGeek Simpler than what? If you don't care about Q or A, you are already as simple as possible. Should the link in the corner include `is:q` automatically on the Questions tab? That would sound like a reasonable request, that's true.

Comment: I thin that he means a search box that is dedicated to  searching the users questions, comments, and answers and will do nothing else.

Comment: @NoviceSEMetaGeek That's a function duplicating. Completely unnecessary. The search-fu is able to do it, and even easily. I take including `is:q/a` in the proper places by default as a good request. It's only my opinion and the SE team may see it differently or course.

Comment: I understand that users can already search by using the following format method in the regular search box:

user:123456 (where 123456 is their userID)

However, the aforementioned format method is still relatively too technical for a person who is Not very computer IT savvy. Please keep in mind that a lot of people who use subsites like https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ and/or https://christianity.stackexchange.com/ and/or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ probably come from a Non-Computer/Non-IT background.

Answer (score 1):

You can already limit results to a specific user account using advanced search operators. It's even easier to limit to your own posts:

```
user:me is:question your search string
```

If you want to use tags, just add them to the search

```
user:me is:question your search string [tag-name]
```

`user:me` automatically expands out to `user:{user-id}`.

Lots more goodies at [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), including details on the advanced search operators. No need for a new feature, I don't think. With this you don't even need to go to the profile page.

Comment: I understand that users can already search by using the following format method in the regular search box:

user:123456 (where 123456 is their userID)

However, the aforementioned format method is still relatively too technical for a person who is Not very computer IT savvy. Please keep in mind that a lot of people who use subsites like https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ and/or https://christianity.stackexchange.com/ and/or https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ probably come from a Non-Computer/Non-IT background.